# How to disable unused style warning in svelte

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a CSS rule which I used for global style, the style worked but my terminal keep show me this warning, how can I disable it?

```
src/components/Navbar.svelte changed. rebuilding...
• server
src/routes/index.svelte
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader-hot/index.js):
Unused CSS selector "*" (22:2)
20: 
21: <style global>
22:   * {
      ^
23:     font-family: 'Poppins';
24:   }
• client
src/routes/index.svelte
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader-hot/index.js):
Unused CSS selector "*" (22:2)
20: 
21: <style global>
22:   * {
      ^
23:     font-family: 'Poppins';
24:   }
✔ service worker (73ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting but I can't find anything about the `<style global>` in the official documentation. Where did you see that this syntax is supported?

To fix that you can use the [`:global(*)`](https://svelte.dev/docs#style) modifier instead of just the `*` selector or move all global styles into a separated `global.css` file (useful to declare styles for `*`, `body`, `a`, ...). You can find a basic svelte project architecture in the [official  template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) and there is a `/src/public/global.css` file.

Comment: sorry man, honestly I don't remember why i wrote <style global>

Comment: @RobyCigar ahah in this case I guess it's just not svelte valid :)

Comment: @johannchopin it is not part of Svelte but it is part of Svelte Preprocess https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#global-style

Answer (score 1):

In rollup.config.js

```js
export default {
    plugins: [
         svelte({
            onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
                const { code, frame, filename } = warning
                if (code === "css-unused-selector" && filename == 'src/routes/index.svelte') {
                    return;
                }
                handler(warning)
            },

         }),
      ]
    }
```